# Combining elements of the same index from two lists in C#

Tags: c#

I have two lists:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=["Ham","Cheese","Bacon"]
```

I want to take each element with the same index in each list and combine them into a resulting list like the below:

```
["1 Ham", "2 Cheese","3 Bacon"]
```

Where either list can be empty.

Answer (score -2):

I tried the below and it worked for me:

```
var list1= [1,2,3];
var list2=["Ham","Cheese","Bacon"];

var list3=list1.Count>0? list1.Zip(list2??Enumerable.Empty<string>(),(first,second)=> first+ " "+ second).ToList():list2;
```

Comment: What's the need for the ternary operators and null coalescing operators? You don't state that either list can be _null_, and `Zip` works perfectly fine if both lists have zero elements.

Comment: If fact, you're only null checking `list2`, and _only_ if `list1` has elements. If `list1` is empty, you always return the value of `list2`, even if that's null.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for your comments. I wanted the `list2` to be returned regardless of what was in it if the `list1` didn't have any elements. I did do a count on the elements in  `list1` before applying the `Zip` method.